# SQL (Postgres) getting one row for each item in a list parameter with an order of preference specified by another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

(Using recent postgres)

Consider table contact_methods

```
id | person | contact_type | other_data
1  | 1      | ""           | stuff
2  | 1      | "mobile"     | important stuff
3  | 2      | "mobile"     | still relevant
4  | 3      | ""           | interesting
```

and a requirement to pull out 1 contact method for the specified person with a preference for rows where the contact type is specified (not empty string "").

I can work out how to get the correct answer when I need to get the contact_method row for one person. Give me contact_method for person 1:

```
SELECT * FROM contact_methods WHERE person = '1' ORDER BY contact_type DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Which would result in the row with id 2.

But I need to support getting a list of one contact method each for a list of people in a single query. E.g. Give me results for persons [1, 2, 3]

Which should result in rows with ids 2, 3 and 4. Is there an efficient way of doing this in one query?

Comment: not sure to understand where the problem is. Use `group by person`, remove LIMIT 1 and change `WHERE person IN (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (person) cm.* 
FROM contact_methods cm
WHERE person IN ('1', '2', '3')
ORDER BY person, contact_type DESC;
```

See: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number()` window function to assign each method per person a number from the "highest" to "lowest" method. The empty string is the "lowest" string there is, so it will be sorted at the last position. From there select the rows with such a number being 1. If a non empty method for a person exists, it'll have a 1.

```
SELECT id,
       person,
       contact_type,
       other_data
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    person,
                    contact_type,
                    other_data,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY person
                                       ORDER BY contact_type DESC) rn
                    FROM contact_methods
                    WHERE person IN (1,
                                     2,
                                     3)) x
       WHERE rn = 1;
```